# Registering a controller with F# and asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I am starting to learn F# and working on it with asp.net core 3.0.

It seems like I am stuck early on.
I have registered the controllers and have onle one controller 'Type' declared, but when I try to access the webpage via Chrome - I get a 404.

Please advise.

Here is my controller and statup.

```
 namespace FSharpDemos

open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

type Startup() =

    member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddControllers() |> ignore

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IWebHostEnvironment) =
        if env.IsDevelopment() then
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore

        app.UseRouting() |> ignore

        app.UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
            endpoints.MapGet("/", fun context -> context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!")) |> ignore
            ) |> ignore



        app.UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
                   endpoints.MapControllers() |> ignore
                   ) |> ignore
```

Here  is my controller

```
  module DocumentController

    open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
    open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc


    [<Route("api/[controller]")>]
    [<ApiController>]
    type DocumentController () =
        inherit ControllerBase()

        [<HttpGet>]
        member this.Get() =
            let values = [|"value1"; "value2"|]
            ActionResult<string[]>(values)
```

Comment: Which endpoint are you trying? `/` or `/api/Document`?

Answer (score 4):

Note the class within a F# module will be compiled into a **nested** class. By default, the ASP.NET Core only considers **public top-level** classes as controllers. In other words, the controllers should be placed within a top level namespace by default.

To fix the 404, the easiest way is to replace the `module` declaration with a `namespace` :

```
module DocumentController
namespace FSharpDemos.Controllers

    open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
    open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

    ...
```

Or if you like, you can add a custom `ControllerFeatureProvider`.